# Can't Find Where a Custom Property is Being Defined or Set

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm a SQL Server developer who is now supporting Access databases.  The VBA code below refers to a custom property referenced by Me![SwitchboardID] in an On Click event handler.  The form has a local table as its Record Source called "Switchboard Items".

I have searched every VBA file and module in the database and the property is not defined or set in code, so I assume it must be somewhere in the Access GUI.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?

```
Private Function HandleButtonClick(intBtn As Integer)
  
    Dim con As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim stSql As String

    ' Find the item in the Switchboard Items table
    ' that corresponds to the button that was clicked.
    Set con = Application.CurrentProject.Connection
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    stSql = "SELECT * FROM [Switchboard Items] "
    stSql = stSql & "WHERE [SwitchboardID]=" & Me![SwitchboardID] & " AND [ItemNumber]=" & intBtn
    ...
```

I have searched through every code file and checked the Properties on the Form and Command Button.  I also checked the Database properties in File > Options > Current Database.

Comment: The property you are looking for may be set in the "Switchboard Manager" which is part of the Access UI. The Switchboard Manager is still available in recent versions of Access but you will need to add it to the Ribbon. [Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-and-use-a-switchboard-f8b3d607-8f1f-4ecf-9979-79b1565f5471) is the Microsoft explanation which may help.

Comment: @user10186832, thank you for the comment.  This pointed me in the right direction.  After stepping through the code and looking at the definition, SwitchboardID is a hidden Access Field property on Form_Switchboard.

Comment: you are welcome, come back soon, stay longer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to @user10186832 and @Albert D. Kallal for pointing me in the right direction.

After stepping through the code and viewing the definition on the Me![SwitchboardID] property, it turned out that SwitchboardID is a built-in, hidden, AccessField property on Form_Switchboard.

The value is set automatically as part of the legacy Switchboard functionality.

[image: Built-in SwitchboardID on the Switchboard form]

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I don't have anything with a switch board (they go back to Access 2003 (a whopping 20 years ago!).

So, the only objects I see being used here are:

The table called [Switchboard Items]. As you note, that's a local table.

And the routine in question looks to be passed an integer value (intBut). So, I assume that on the switchboard there is/are say 1-6 buttons. I would look at the click event of those buttons, and a best (obvious) guess would be that each click event calls the above routine, and passes a simple integer value called IntBut.

So, look at the click event of the button(s) on the switchboard. It will be either a macro, or a VBA click event. That button click event when called thus is likely to be calling your above routine, and passing a simple integer value (called intBtn) to this posted function.

So, what the posted code does is select from the table, and filters to a given intBtn id of some value.

The switchboard table will have the columns of itemNumber, ItemText etc.

So, in effect the switchboard is a "data driven" form in which the button options are feed from a data table (options are not hard coded in VBA).

Hence "me" in access code is the same as C# (and JavaScript) "this", which means the current context. In this case, "me" means the current form. We often use "me" in place of a hard coded form name like Forms!SwtichBoard!SomeControl value. And in vb.net, once again “Me” is used just like in VBA.

Use of "me" thus allows the form name to be changed, and the Forms! Switchboard code behind in that form thus does not require changes in code if the form name is changed when you use "me".

So, in above, I see:

```
[Me]!SwitchBoardID
```

The above will thus be the value of the current record and in that form, thus a database column of SwitchboardID based on the current record of the form in question.

I then see:

intBtn.

Looking at the Function name, we see:

```
Private Function HandleButtonClick(intBtn As Integer)
```

So, the code behind on the switchboard (button click events) obviosity must be passing an integer (likely 1-6 for the button clicked on).

I don't see any particular property, or setting or anything at all that is "hidden".

So, just keep in mind the use of "me" means the same as "this" in C# or JavaScript -- it means the current object in question, or for Access, the current form object. As noted, vb.net also uses “me”.

Hence ALL of the following are the same:

```
Forms!SwitchBoard!ID    -- gets current ID of the form (record or control)
Forms("Switchboard")!ID
Me!ID
```

So, a translation of that code?

Please get me the current row from a given switch board number, and then filter to an intBtn choice.

So, you can have multiple switch boards (kind of like a main menu) and then you can have several choices (1-6 or whatever, and that's the intBtn value being passed).

So, it is not clear what "property" you are looking for.

If you bind a form to any data table, then me!SomeDataBaseColumn is a legal syntax, and simply means return the current record "column" in the current form. As such, these properties don't exist in the form, but they WILL have to exist in the table bound to that form in question.

The above means that you can in code fetch/use/enjoy database columns and no control need be placed on the form to enjoy use of such data columns. As long as the data column exists in the forms data source (the underlying table), then you can use such database columns, and no controls or even property has to exist or be created in that form to enjoy use of that database column. So, the form's data source (the bound data table) thus defines if such expressions are legal or not.

So, Me!SomeDataBase column refers to the current record in the current form, and then to a column from the database table that is bound to that form in question.